# Scala: Implementation of a Seq.distinctOn function

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to implement a distinctOn function for a sequence which will take a function f and return a sequence for which each item has a distinct result when the f is applied to it. EG:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)

val people = Seq(Person("Al", 20), Person("Bob", 21), 
                 Person("Bob", 24)).distinctOn(_.name)

//people should be:

Seq(Person("Al", 20), Person("Bob", 21))
```

where the first duplicate (Al) is returned, and order is preserved. My current implementation contains a var, and my other attempts using Sets and GroupBy didn't preserve order. Is there a better way to implement this without the var? For the record my current attempt is:

```
  def distinctOn[A](f: T => A):Seq[T]={
    var seen = Set[A]()

    seq.foldLeft(Seq[T]()) { (res, curr) => {
      if(!seen.contains(f(curr))){
        seen = seen ++ Set[A](f(curr))
        res ++ Seq(curr)
      }else{
        res
      }
    }}
  }
```

Comment: why not to try use `groupBy` method like that:
`people.groupBy(_.name).map(_._2(0))`

Comment: @RyuuGan, I think that won't preserve the order.

Comment: @RyuuGan, Paul is correct, groupBy doesn't preserve the order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an implementation which preserves order where applicable and also works for other `Traversable`s than `Seq`s. It is based on the implementation of `distinct` and uses the builder factories (a.k.a. `CanBuildFrom`s) used in other collection methods.

```
class TraversableOnceExt[A, CC[A] <: TraversableOnce[A]](coll: CC[A]) {
  import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def distinctBy[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, That]): That = {
    val b = cbf(coll)
    val seen = collection.mutable.HashSet[B]()
    for (x <- coll) {
      val v = f(x)
      if (!seen(v)) {
        b += x
        seen += v
      }
    }
    b.result
  }
}

implicit def commomExtendTraversable[A, C[A] <: TraversableOnce[A]](coll: C[A]): TraversableOnceExt[A, C] =
  new TraversableOnceExt[A, C](coll)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improvement that puts `seen` into the fold and generally cleans things up (like not constructing a collection just to add one element to an existing collection):

```
class EnrichedSeq[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
  def distinctOn[A](f: T => A): Seq[T] = {
    seq.foldLeft((Set[A](), Seq[T]())) {
      case ((seen, res), curr) =>
        val y = f(curr)
        if (!seen(y))
          (seen + y, res :+ curr)
        else
          (seen, res)
    }._2
  }
}
implicit def enrichSeq[T](self: Seq[T]) = new EnrichedSeq(self)
```

Also, you might call it `distinctBy` since that's more in line with the naming convention used by the libraries (eg, `maxBy`, `sortBy`, etc)